# Visual Studio code is super slow

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

I run visual studio code on Windows 10. Current version of my visual studio code is 1.45.1. I am running a Python (version 3.7.4 64-bit) on it. My visual studio code takes 5 to 10 minutes to load following libraries:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime, date
from scipy.stats import ttest_ind
from scipy.stats import ttest_ind_from_stats
from scipy.stats import ttest_1samp
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

I tried to find a solution online to speed up, but couldn't find it. Is anyone experience the same issue? How could we speed up the visual code?

Comment: Do you suspect any of these modules specifically? What is `import_datasets `? It does not look like a standard module to me.

Comment: It was working fine yesterday. It was bit lagging but today its super slow. I removed the import_datasets but it did not make any difference.

Comment: How quickly does this Python script take to import everything when run outside of VS Code? If you quit and restart VS Code does it make a difference?

Comment: I ran the code on jupyter notebook. It took almost same amount of time to load up the libraries. I restarted the visual code and machine but did not make any difference.

Comment: You can easily time how long each import takes by printing out the current time between each import statement. That will help you identify the problem.

Comment: "*I ran the code on jupyter notebook. It took almost same amount of time to load up the libraries.*" If it's slow even outside VS Code, then it's probably not a VS Code problem.

Comment: Which language server are you using? Jedi or Microsoft? Have you tried both of them?

Answer (score 0):

```
from time import perf_counter
a=perf_counter()
import pandas as pd
b=perf_counter()
import numpy as np
c=perf_counter()
from datetime import datetime, date
d=perf_counter()
from scipy.stats import ttest_ind
e=perf_counter()
from scipy.stats import ttest_ind_from_stats
f=perf_counter()
from scipy.stats import ttest_1samp
g=perf_counter()
import seaborn as sns
h=perf_counter()
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
i=perf_counter()

print(b-a)
print(c-b)
print(d-c)
print(e-d)
print(f-e)
print(g-f)
print(h-g)
print(i-h)
```

Take this to analyze which imports take too much time.

Then take 'cProfile' to do exactly analysis. you can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582336/how-can-you-profile-a-python-script) page.